# Sync alerts over network

Tags: windows, networking

I want to have a simple way to pop up a message and make a sound at certain times across all computers running Windows 10 on a network. It's easy enough to do this with a scheduled batch file, but if we want to change all the times to 10min later, for example, it's not easy to update.

There are two ways I've thought of to do this without resorting to 3rd party software, but struggling with both:

1. I can msg command to send a network message to the computers, but I can't see how to listen for that to generate a sound.
2. To write a batch file that runs on each computer that reads a network file. But I haven't been able to get this working either.

Is there a better way to do this or is one of the above an optimal solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One (of many) solutions would be to run a scheduled task on a remote computer using the following command:

```
﻿schtasks.exe /u <username> /p <user password> /run <server name> /s /tn "<scheduled task name>"
```

Note, you will need admin rights to run the command, you can do this via command line too using `Runas`. There are tons of guides with screenshots etc., just search for `cmd remotely run scheduled task` using your favourite search engine.